# My Grid By click on link is not showing

Tags: javascript, function, extjs, grid

I have this index.html Please read the complete question before answering .

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Reseller DashBoard</title>

    <!-- ** CSS ** -->
    <!-- base library -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ext-all.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/xtheme-gray.css" />

    <!-- overrides to base library -->

    <!-- ** Javascript ** -->
    <!-- ExtJS library: base/adapter -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ext-base-debug.js"></script>

    <!-- ExtJS library: all widgets -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/ext-all-debug.js"></script>

    <!-- overrides to base library -->

    <!-- page specific -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jsfunction.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/reseller.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="dashboard">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my dashboard.js In this i have a rendere function on which generate the hyper link 
on the click of this hyperlink i want to open the another grid which is in the reseller.js.
and the onlclick function is in jsfunction.js.

```
/**
 * this file has the reseller dashboard grid 
 * 
 */
Ext.onReady(function(){

    /** 
    * function for rendering the link
    **/
    function linkRenderer(data, cell, record, rowIndex, columnIndex, store) {
        if  (data != null)  {
            return '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="resellerwindow(\'' +record.data.cityname+'\')">'+ data +'</a>';

        }
        return data;
    }

    // create the data store
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // store configs
        autoDestroy: true,
        autoLoad :true,
        url: 'api/index.php?_command=getresellerscount',
        storeId: 'getresellerscount',
        // reader configs
        root: 'cityarray',
        idProperty: 'cityname',
        fields: [
           {name: 'cityname'},
           {name: 'totfollowup'},
           {name: 'totcallback'},
           {name: 'totnotintrested'},
           {name: 'totdealsclosed'},
           {name: 'totcallsreceived'},
           {name: 'totcallsentered'},
           {name: 'totresellerregistered'},
           {name: 'countiro'},
           {name: 'irotransferred'},
           {name: 'irodeferred'}
        ]
    });


    // create the Grid
    var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                id       :'cityname',
                header   : 'City Name', 
                width    : 120, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'cityname'
            },
            {
                id       :'countiro',
                header   : ' Total Prospect', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'countiro'
            },
             {
                id       :'irotransferred',
                header   : 'Calls Transfered By IRO', 
                height : 50,
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'irotransferred'
            },
            {
                id       :'irodeferred',
                header   : ' Calls Deferred By IRO', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'irodeferred'
            },
            {
                id       :'totcallsentered',
                header   : ' Total Calls Entered', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex : 'totcallsentered',
                renderer : linkRenderer
            },
            {
                id       :'totfollowup',
                header   : ' Follow Up', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'totfollowup'
            },
            {
                id       :'totcallback',
                header   : ' Call Backs', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'totcallback'
            },
            {
                id       :'totnotintrested',
                header   : ' Not Interested', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'totnotintrested'
            },
            {
                id       :'totdealsclosed',
                header   : ' Deals Closed', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'totdealsclosed'
            },
             {
                id       :'totresellerregistered',
                header   : ' Reseller Registered', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'totresellerregistered'
            }
        ],
        height: 350,
        width: 1060,
        title: 'Reseller Dashboard',
        // config options for stateful behavior

    });

    // render the grid to the specified div in the page
    grid.render('dashboard');
});
```

Here is my jsfunction.js , is it the right place to place the code of the link click handler  or should i place it any where else .

```
  /**
   * function for opening the window of reseller grid 
   *
   **/
    function resellerwindow(cityname) {
        alert(cityname);
        // render the grid to the specified div in the page
        resellergrid.render('dashboard');

    }
```

Here is my reseller.js which has the another grid coding , Please suggest the coding in this file is right or should i change something .

```
/**
 * this file has the reseller grid 
 * 
 */
Ext.onReady(function(){

    // create the data store
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        // store configs
        autoDestroy: true,
        autoLoad :true,
        url: 'api/index.php?_command=getresellers',
        storeId: 'getresellerscount',
        // reader configs
        root: 'reseller',
        idProperty: 'firstname',
        fields: [
           {name: 'firstname'},
           {name: 'lastname'},
           {name: 'mobile'},
           {name: 'email'},
           {name: 'tmecode'},
           {name: 'tmename'},
           {name: 'updatedon'},
           {name: 'apptype'},
           {name: 'alloctype'},
           {name: 'empparent'},
           {name: 'irodeferred'}
        ]
    });


    // create the Grid
    var resellergrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
        columns: [
            {
                id       :'firstname',
                header   : 'First Name', 
                width    : 120, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'firstname'
            },
            {
                id       :'lastname',
                header   : ' Last Name', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'lastname'
            },
             {
                id       :'mobile',
                header   : 'Mobile', 
                height : 50,
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'mobile'
            },
            {
                id       :'email',
                header   : 'E-Mail', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'email'
            },
            {
                id       :'tmecode',
                header   : ' TME Code', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex : 'tmecode'
            },
            {
                id       :'updatedon',
                header   : ' updatedon', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'updatedon'
            },
            {
                id       :'empparent',
                header   : ' empparent', 
                width    : 100, 
                sortable : true, 
                dataIndex: 'empparent'
            }
        ],
        height: 350,
        width: 1060,
        title: 'Reseller Dashboard',
        // config options for stateful behavior

    });


});
```

My Main problem is the why the reseller grid is not showing i am getting this error while click on the link in dashboard grid

```
resellergrid is not defined
[Break on this error] resellergrid.render('dashboard');
```

Comment: the grid showing by Abdel answer help now but i want to call the reseller.js store with the data of cityname passing in the api , and i changed little in resller.js i added the window in this which has item is resellergrid so how should i proceed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two onReady methods. Your application need only one onReady method.

The error is because resellergrid is not define within the scope of the resellerwindow(). You have declared the resellergrid in reseller.js. But is not accessible for the resellerwindow.

Comment: So how should i organise my code in respect of onReady and resellerwindow(). Should i remove the onready from reseller.js is that ok ?

Comment: @Abdel the grid showing now but i want to call the reseller.js store  with the data of `cityname` passing in the api , and i changed little in resller.js i added the window in this which has item is resellergrid so how should i proceed ?

Comment: can i call this resellerwindow function in other file ? i tried in dashboard.js but it was giving error ?

Comment: ok, its high time you come up with a good architecture for the app. Read http://blog.extjs.eu/know-how/writing-a-big-application-in-ext/ , http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?92514-Advice-on-structuring-a-large-ExtJS-application etc for starting

Comment: It will take time to read and understand any way i want to do that , can you help me here how can i proceed now ASAP.

Comment: This is the nice post link you provided . Thanks

Comment: @Abdel if i develope using this blog post , is that will work well ?